# Best way to transform an array of ints into a bitset representation in C++?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, data-mining, bitset, bitvector

I've seen some similar questions on the topic, but I'm relatively new to programming and couldn't make sense of some of the language used in the solutions.

Suppose I have 2 finite sets A,B represented as arrays where:

```
int A[2] = {1, 3};
int B[2] = {1, 2};
```

I want the bitsets (column vectors V) that represent A and B.

```
    v1 v2
(1) 1, 1
(2) 0, 1
(3) 1, 0
```

This way I can easily sum row (k) and get the count of appearances for the value k across all of my sets A_1 to A_n.

I am looking for the fastest possible way to do this. I can roughly imagine how I might first initialize a matrix of bit vectors (setting each value to 0) and then loop through each set A_i, setting the corresponding entry of my matrix to 1, but this solution seems useless, because I still have to loop through every element in every set A_i.

I am trying to avoid having to loop through every element of every set by instead getting the count of appearances by summing rows of bits, but I can't figure out how to elegantly make this transformation in a time efficient manner.

Motivation: I'm trying to implement the ID3 decision tree algorithm and am trying to use bit vectors to calculate proportions of labels for entropy calculation.

Comment: For some reason the "suppose I have 2 _finite_ sets" cracks me up. Don't even have to look at the name to see this is a mathematician :D

Comment: It's unclear though how you expect to solve this problem by performing _less_ work than at least reading every element of each set at least once. Unless there is some structure in the set elements that you didn't tell us about, it's trivially impossible to process all the information in `A` and `B` if you're not allowed to look at all their elements. Maybe it would help to add information on how `A` and `B` are generated/built? (PS: I think you have a typo in the first snippet).

Comment: If what you're after is just the appearance count of each element, why not use a (hash) map instead of several bitvectors? You'll still have to inspect each set element once (see above), but instead of summing bits after the fact you can just increment a counter in the map... Or, since your values appear to be dense, a simple array?

Comment: math comment cracked me up lol. I agree that it's unclear how to do this without at least looking at every element once. I was trying to follow an implementation of an algorithm online and it seemed to me like the author was suggesting there was a way to convert the representations without inspecting each element. 

Its from the following pdf: https://mltrain.cc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ryan-curtin.pdf ... and on slide 139 where he seemed he was suggesting this was possbile

Comment: @mathsterjedi Actually, if you have no additional information about how the sets are constructed, it is impossible to do it without iterating over the sets. How would it be ? You cannot describe the contents of a container if you cannot take a look at what it contains (the same as if I asked you to describe what's inside an opaque black box, without any additional information, you have no way to guess what's inside neither how to describe it, except if you're God :) ).

Comment: @Fareanor I am constructing my sets using k-grams on lines of text. Line 1 - "Sam runs", line 2 - "Sam swims". I parse the line of text into sets A = {"Sam", "runs"}, B = {"Sam", "swims"}. Changing representation to ints gives A ={1, 2}, B = {1,3}. Now I want to count the # of appearances of the word "Sam". It seemed fastest way to do this was to construct the bit vectors and then sum the k'th row to get the number of appearances for value k. 

I'm very new to programming so I wasn't sure if there was a way to construct these bit vectors without looping through each element in each set.

Comment: There are potentially billions of unique words in the text file. Now you want to create a vector with one bit per word. That's billions of bits for every line. And you potentially have billions of lines of text. So you have billions of billions of bits. Lets hope ram prizes drop. And then you want to sum them up. So you need an int (better would be a uint64_t or size_t) per unique word and not just a bit. You really should not construct the bit vectors. Create the result vector with all 0 and then add to that directly as you parse the sets.

Comment: this makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in the presentation is that you don't explicitly form the sets just to build bitsets from them, but construct the bitsets *instead* of the sets.

In short, you have

```
std::vector<double> unsortedDataInRow(numDataInRow) = ...;
std::vector<int> labels(numLabels) = ...;
```

You then obtain

```
std::vector<unsigned> sortedIndices = getSortedIndices(unsortedDataInRow);
```

so that `unsortedDataInRow[sortedIndices[i]]` is sorted. But instead of building `std::vector<int> sortedLabels` from them, you instead fill a

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> bitsets(numLabels, std::vector<bool>(numDataInRow));
// this gets zero-initialized
```

in such a way that `bitsets[label][i] == (unsortedLabels[sortedIndices[i]] == label)`:

```
for (auto sortedIndex : sortedIndices)
  bitsets[unsortedLabels[sortedIndices]][sortedIndex] = true;
```

This helps performance because you (presumably) do the label counting in `InfoGain` (i.e. determining `P(c)`, which can then be done much faster through `popcnt` than through `counts[labels[i]]++;`) much more often than you do the above.

Note that this is just a sketch - `std::vector<bool>` doesn't have an inbuilt way to get a `popcnt`. You'd have to hope that your compiler recognizes a handwritten one. Alternatively, use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), or some other library, or a handwritten one.

Comment: This was my suspicion as well but it was quite unclear to me. I have up-voted this as the correct answer. Thank you for taking the time!